# Connect MongoDB with Web API

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to connect MongoDB with Web API in Visual Studio 2013. All I want to do is create a simple database with C#. All of my code is in ValuesControllers.cs file. I created a simple Model class -

```
public class Book
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } 
}
```

and modified the Get method

```
public IEnumerable<Book> Get()
{
     MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
     var server = client.GetServer();
     var db = server.GetDatabase("BookStore");
     var collection = db.GetCollection<Book>("Book");
     Book[] books = new Book[] 
     { 
            new Book {Id = 1, Title="Book Name 1" },
            new Book {Id = 2, Title="Book Name 2" },
            new Book {Id = 3, Title="Book Name 3" },
            new Book {Id = 4, Title="Book Name 4" }

     };
     collection.Save(books);
     return books;
}
```

It returns values but doesn't create database. I tried this in console application and it works. 
I want to make a simple example to connect MongoDB.

Comment: collection.InsertBatch(books)

Comment: foreach (var book in books)
            {
                collection.Insert(book);
            }

Comment: @Disposer,  Still not creating database. Could you tell me how can I get values or returns values from MongoDB database that is created with any MongoDB tools like Robomongo in Web API?

Comment: What do you mean "not creating database"? How do you verify this? Are you looking at the same MongoDB instance as the one this code is connecting to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work. Make sure you have the mongo database running in the background.

I've modified your code as follows

1. I've added mongo connection URL when creating the MongoClient object
   so it will connect to local mongo Db.
2. When saving the Books to the
   DB, instead of trying to save the array directly to the DB, the code
   is now looping over each item and saving it individually.

Here is the code

```
public IEnumerable<Book> Get()
{     
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var server = client.GetServer();
    var db = server.GetDatabase("BookStore");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<Book>("Book");
    Book[] books =
    {
         new Book { Id = 1, Title = "Book Name 1" }, 
         new Book { Id = 2, Title = "Book Name 2" },
         new Book { Id = 3, Title = "Book Name 3" }, 
         new Book { Id = 4, Title = "Book Name 4" }
    };
    foreach (var book in books)
    {
        collection.Save(book);
    }
    return books;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you did and why you think it will solve OP's problem instead of just dumping code. Also, the parameterless constructor of `MongoClient` connects to localhost at port 27017.