# Getting Data From MongoDB using Web API

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I have a database that created in MongoDB using Robomongo tool. How can I get these data in Web API by its default Get method in ValuesControllers.cs?

As we know that when we use this url api/values, we get a json file. I want my data like this.

Database name : StudentInfo
Collection Name : Student

```
{
  _id : ObjectId(),
  name : "lqbal",
  department : "CSE",
  phone : "0194949402"
}
```

Comment: is this the same question as you raised here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335929/connect-mongodb-with-web-api/28341404#28341404  I've added an answer to this question

Comment: @Kevin , Your answer helped me there. But there I created database using c#. But here I created database using Robomongo tool. I want to get/access data from the database created in Robomongo tool.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document from a collection that was created by RoboMongo. that will help to define the c# entity needed to read the data

Comment: Database Name : StudentInfo
Collection Name : Student

it has 3 field: name, department and phone . _id field is by default.

This is image
http://jpst.it/wvmp

Comment: I've updated my answer below with sample code

Comment: It shows an error

http://jpst.it/wvxh

Comment: I've added the list of include statements to my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to build a Data Access layer that will take the values passed in the API request and execute queries against the DB. 
Once you have the results from the DB in c# entities, the web-api will be able to automatically convert these into JSON responses.

You can define a c# entity to represent the Student document

```
public class Student
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string department { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
    }
```

Add these includes to the top of your class

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

Then your API Get method is as follows

```
public Student Get(string id)
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var db = server.GetDatabase("StudentInfo");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<Student>("Student");

            var student = ((MongoCollection)collection).AsQueryable<Student>().First(c => c.name == id);
            return student;
        }
```

The connection part as standard to specify the Database and collection to use.
The query part is done by using the LINQ extensions that are available via the c# mongo driver. You can query the DB collection by writting a LINQ query- the driver will automatically create the actual query required to execute on the DB.

Once you have the student document, you can just return it. The WebApi framework will automatically convert it into a JSON document

The API result should look like

```
{
"Id": "54d3575c5157ba55281006a5",
"name": "lqbal",
"department": "CSE",
"phone": "0194949402"
}
```